# How to view result from JSON API in browser

Tags: android, json

I have a JSON API URL "http://myurl/getDataMethod" this takes a parameter "parameter1". How can I call this API in browser to view its result? Can I use JSFiddle to see the result on runtime? If not then can you provide code for viewing the result in Android app?

I tried calling the API in android App but I got error java.io.FileNotFoundException:, I don;t know why. Also my parameter is having @ symbol which is getting converted to %40 when I call the URL through code in APP. I just want to view the data from this API by passing parameter, please help/advise. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can always use an API Tester tool like `Postman` for testing/viewing the response received from an API. Also if your API method is `GET`, you can even use a browser by passing the relevant query parameters.
2. When you try to call an API from a browser, the entire URL gets Encoded so `@` becomes `%40`

Comment: In the API documentation it is given API URL: http://someURL/getDataByParameter
API BODY:
{
    "Parameter_ID" : 'Value'
}, How can I call this in browser? Can I do http://someURL/getDataByParameter?Parameter_ID=value ? I tried calling like this but not getting success.. I just want to view the result in browser

Comment: So you need to ensure that the API expects a GET method which can be called from a browser, for passing the parameters you can use the query string parameters like you have shown above. Lastly, rather than taking parameters from body, just replace the code to take input from query parameters and pass it to your DB to fetch the results.

Answer (score 0):

Use Postman software to access your api and its data anytime before you start coding so as to know the data structure and flow.
Refer to the Postman tutorials or official documentation to learn more about the working

Postman documentation link:
https://learning.getpostman.com/docs/postman/api-documentation/documenting-your-api/